# How to make entire div clickable(into a link)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made many changes on this code but it didn't work, what step should I follow? I want to make whole section that include icon and button's text clickable. I have tried this method already but not sure is it true or not: `onclick="location.href='http://www.example.com';"`

You can make corrections as you want, I'm open to any help, thank you.

```css
#ana_div {
  height: 400px;
  width: 960px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.ikon {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  position: absolute;
}

.div {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 80px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.btn {
  border: none;
  color: black;
  height: 80px;
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 19px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
}
```

```html
<div id="ana_div">

  <div class="div" id="div">
    <div class="ikon">
      <img src="icon.png">
    </div>
    <button class="btn"> button1
            </button>
  </div>

  <div class="div" id="div">
    <div class="ikon">
      <img src="icon.png">
    </div>
    <button class="btn"> button2
            </button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What happened when you tried that?

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't have multiple DIVs with the same ID.

Comment: make it clickable in order to do what? There are no urls shown. what exactly is your desired result?

Comment: it was not clickable when i add url, i know ID things, just demo.

Comment: A div is clickable by nature, are you trying to run javascript when you click a divs block? You can add CSS to indicate a hand when you hover over the div to let users know clicking on te div will do something.

Comment: Looks to me like you need to add ***proper*** javascript that will run when you click the DIV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't want to use JS in your code, just add a tag before your columns

check this code

```css
#ana_div {
    height: 400px;
    width: 960px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.ikon {
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    position: absolute;
}

.div {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 80px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.btn {
    border: none;
    color: black;
    height: 80px;
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 19px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
}
```

```html
 <div id="ana_div">
    <a href="https://google.com">
        <div class="div" id="div">
          <div class="ikon">
            <img src="icon.png">
          </div>
          <button class="btn"> button1</button>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="https://microsoft.com">
        <div class="div" id="div">
          <div class="ikon">
            <img src="icon.png">
          </div>
          <button class="btn"> button2</button>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is as simple as it gets, a div tag enclosed by an anchor tag.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.big-div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/">
  <div class="big-div">
    <p>Click anywhere</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write button click like this:

```
<button onclick=" window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank'); return false;">Continue</button>
```

Comment: Its work for me, many thanks. Can we make it clickable with new tab(open in new tab smth).

Comment: @JozefStone I have updated my answer so please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Add an anchor tag and add the href attribute to it. Then add some style to remove the line and change the color. finally you can add anything you want inside it.
Otherwise you can create a anchor tag add the href and id. inside the onclick function of your div call a function redirect(). Inside the redirect() function  add this code:
`document.getElementById("your-tag-id").click()`

Comment: Thanks for feedback, i already try anchor, a hreft etc. Whenever i try anything, it just make only buttons text area clickable, not entire div or button.

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing div into anchor tag.

```
<a href= "http://www.example.com">
<div id="ana_div">

  <div class="div" id="div">
    <div class="ikon">
      <img src="icon.png">
    </div>
    <button class="btn"> button1
            </button>
  </div>

  <div class="div" id="div">
    <div class="ikon">
      <img src="icon.png">
    </div>
    <button class="btn"> button2
            </button>
  </div>

</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Now it's exactly what I wanted, but how can I change the link of the second button while it's in this state?

Comment: I do not understand what you are looking for. So you want to redirect user to 2 different links based on two different buttons? For that you can enclose button one in one anchor tag and second button in other anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an event listener, then you can use a function to run the javascript you wish when the user clicks the ***div*** / ***button***.

As for your redirect, you can create a new `<a>` tag element using JS, then add the appropriate attributes for ***target***, ***src*** and lastly, use the ***click()*** function on it.

[See JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7fv35wtc/)

### Javascript:

```
let btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')

function redirectHeader(){
  let url = 'https://google.com'
  const a = document.createElement('a')
  a.target = '_blank'
  a.href = url
  a.click()
}

btn.forEach(button => {  
  button.addEventListener('click', redirectHeader)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

OK now I understood. Use this code snippet:

```
<div id="ana_div">
  <a href="https://example.com">
  <div class="div" id="div">
    <div class="ikon">
      <img src="icon.png">
    </div>
    <button class="btn"> button1
            </button>
  </div>
  </a>
  
  <a href="https://example.com">
  <div class="div" id="div">
    <div class="ikon">
      <img src="icon.png">
    </div>
    <button class="btn"> button2
            </button>
  </div>
  </a>

</div>
```